# datasets.Dataset.set_transform() doesn't seem to apply transformations to images

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, torchvision, huggingface-datasets

I have some pretty simple code where I download a dataset from the HuggingFace datasets library, try to resize it, and create a dataloader from it. However, I get error messages that the images cannot be stacked as they are still of the original size in the dataset, despite the resize() function being applied:

```
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Compose, Resize
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset_name = 'food101'
size = 255

resize = Compose([Resize(size),ToTensor()])

dataset = load_dataset(dataset_name, split='train')
dataset.set_transform(resize)
dataset.set_format('torch')
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32)

for batch in dataloader:
  print(inputs)
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [512, 384, 3] at entry 0 and [512, 512, 3] at entry 1

I'm extremely confused here. Whether I use set_transform() or with_transform(), it does not seem like the transformation is ever actually applied. What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried applying it with a function like this, which didn't make a difference:

```
def transform(examples):
  examples['image'] = [resize(img) for img in examples['image']]
  return examples

dataset.set_transform(transform)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, according to the [datasets docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.11.0/package_reference/main_classes.html?highlight=set_format#datasets.Dataset.set_transform) the `dataset.set_format` method resets the transformations. So, since you are transforming the images to Pytorch tensor inside the `resize` transforms, I believe there is no need for `set_format`. (But you could still apply it **before** the `set_transform` just to make sure)

Second, if images are all of different height and length sizes, you should provide both dimensions to the `Resize((size, size))` transforms.

overall, this would work:

```py
resize = Compose([Resize((size, size)),ToTensor()])

def transform(examples):
  examples['image'] = [resize(img) for img in examples['image']]
  return examples

# dataset.set_format('torch')
dataset.set_transform(transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32)
```

Note that the `transform(examples)` function is still required.

```py
for batch in dataloader:
    print(batch.keys())
    print(batch['image'].shape)
    print(batch['label'].shape)
    break
```

```
>>>
dict_keys(['image', 'label'])
torch.Size([32, 3, 255, 255])
torch.Size([32])
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Removing the set_format() solved it, I did not understand that it resets the dataset.